# Magento how to remove a class from Layout

Tags: magento

I have add a body class to default layout (local.xml) and I want to remove it in some specific area. Tried to use `removeBodyClass` but Magento 1.7.0.2 shows me an error "Invalid method Mage_Page_Block_Html::removeBodyClass(Array..."

How to solve that? 
addBodyClass is working, removeBodyClass cause problems. Please give me a solution. Thanks in Advance

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="addBodyClass"><classname>halloweenClass</classname></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no class exits on  removeBodyClass  in magento CE 1.7.

and if want to do this then rewrite `Mage_Page_Block_Html` class then  add  function `removeBodyClass`

```css
  public function removeBodyClass($className)
    {
        $className = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]+#', '-', strtolower($className));

        $this->setBodyClass(str_replace($className,' ',$this->getBodyClass()). ' ' . $className);

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Amit thanks for the quick answer you pointed me in the correct place but your code should be fixed a bit. If you want it to perfectly work it should be as $this->setBodyClass(str_replace($className,'',$this->getBodyClass()). '');